# Painting the stack with dummy value

Tags: c, stack, embedded

I am trying to find the maximum stack usage of the embedded program. For this I am filling the stack with dummy value. I generated the .su files and I approximated the maximum stack usage to be around 35,523 B. I am trying to get the same value by painting the stack with dummy value. Since I know that approximated stack usage is around 35KB,I define `STACK_SIZE` to be 40kB. I paint the stack from  `STACK_TOP` till `STACK_TOP - STACK_SIZE` with `0XDEADBEEF`. However, I don't get 35,523 KB as the stack usage and the stack usage changes everytime if I change the `STACK_SIZE` to values other than 40KB.What am I doing wrong?

In startup.c before calling main,I do this.

```
src = STACK_START;
dst = STACK_END;
while(src < dst){
  *(src++) = 0xDEADBEEF;
```

Then after running the program, I count the stack usage like this:

```
uint16_t StackCount(void)
{
  
    volatile unsigned long *start, *end;
    start = STACK_START;
    end = STACK_END;
    uint32_t       countBytes = 0;

    while((*start == 0xDEADBEEF && start < end))
    {
        start++;
        countBytes++;
                
    }
        
    printf("stack used:%d bytes \n",STACK_SIZE-countBytes);
    printf("remaining stack :%d bytes\n",countBytes);
         
    return c;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of abstracting away values like STACK_START and STACK_END if you are going to hard-code a 42000 literal further down in the code?

Comment: (In other words: what you are doing wrong is probably that `42000`.)

Comment: You're counting 32-bit values, but only adding one to 'c' for each, which you then seem to treat as a byte count.

Comment: Would recommend changing the badly named 'c' variable to something more descriptive, like count_bytes or count_longs. Then use that in the appropriate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see two places where this program went wrong:

> Since I know that approximated stack usage is around 35KB,I define STACK_SIZE to be 40kB

I don't think this is the right idea. From what I can tell from the question, I think that `STACK_START` and `STACK_END` are pointers to the start and end of the memory allocated for the stack right? If so, instead, you want to calculate STACK_SIZE like this: `((uint8_t*)STACK_END - (uint8_t*)STACK_START)`. Why this instead of the 40kB assumption constant? -- this is the total amount of memory that the program paints before main, so I think its the right assumption that this is the total stack size you want to be tracking against your actual usage.
Why the casts to `uint8_t *?` - because I don't know how `STACK_START` and `STACK_END` are defined, if these are defined as other pointer types, like `uint32_t *STACK_START`, then this pointer arithmatic is going to be couning the number of 4-byte words in the stack, and not the number of bytes.

---

```
    uint32_t * start...
    
    while((*start == 0xDEADBEEF && start < end))
    {
        start++;
        countBytes++;
                
    }
```

Secondly, this loop is now counting the number of 4-byte words in the stack, not the total number of bytes in the stack. This is another spot where pointer arithmatic is doing something unexpected.

---

Lastly, I fixed the bugs I saw and typed up a local 'mock' version of this program that you can use to test locally. It might help you to run this locally to better see how the stack is being manipulated.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/* Dummy stack definitions.
 * Allocate "dummy_stack" that this program paints & counts instead of the real program stack.
 * I assume that constants STACK_START and STACK_END are defined in some linker script somewhere.
 * */
// Define how big the stack is in 4-byte words
#define DUMMY_STACK_SIZE 42000
uint32_t dummy_stack[DUMMY_STACK_SIZE];

uint32_t * STACK_START = &dummy_stack[0];
uint32_t * STACK_END = &dummy_stack[DUMMY_STACK_SIZE-1];

/* \ Dummy defs */

/* Your real functions */


void StackPaint(void)
{
        uint32_t *src;
        uint32_t *dst;
        src = STACK_START;
        dst = STACK_END;
        while(src < dst){
          *(src++) = 0xDEADBEEF;
        }
}

uint16_t StackCount(void)
{
    uint32_t * start = STACK_START;
    uint32_t * end = STACK_END;
    uint32_t c = 0;

    // Calculate the total space allocated from the stack from STACK_START and STACK_END
    const uint32_t STACK_SIZE = ((uint8_t*)STACK_END - (uint8_t*)STACK_START);

    while((*start == 0xDEADBEEF && start < end))
    {
        start++;
        c+=sizeof(uint32_t);

    }

    printf("stack used: %d bytes \n",STACK_SIZE-c);
    printf("remaining stack :%d bytes\n",c);

    return c;
}

/* \ Your real functions */

/* Local test framework */
int main() {
        // Paint the fake stack before counting
        StackPaint();

        // Do something to wipe paint off the stack
        dummy_stack[1000] = 0xBEEFCAFE;

        // Count how many bytes were used
        StackCount();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be clearer if DUMMY_STACK_SIZE was a byte count like everything else. And STACK_END seems to be off-by one. Also the dreaded 'c' variable is back :-). But pretty good.

Comment: I'd also swap the order of the conditions in while((*start == 0xDEADBEEF && start < end)), otherwise you (potentially) overrun the array before testing that you're still within it.